# Hide/Show Navigation Link On Site

Tags: jquery, html, navigation, hide, show

I have added a fixed navigation link to the site I have also included this in the forums and blog.

The navigation link might get annoying to users when they are trying to browse the forums so how I can add functionality if they click a link "Hide Navigation" it will hide the navigation bar even if they refresh the page it will still be hidden until they click "Show Navigation" link

Here's what I have quickly written up but it does not work and I am not sure how to add this functionality

```
<html>
<!-- Some html -->

<body>
  <a href='#' id='hide'> Hide Navigation </a>

  <text id='data'><br>Data Here</text>

  <a href='#' id='show' style='display:none;'> Show Navigation</a>
</body>

<script src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js'></script>

<script>
$( document ).ready(function() { 

    $("#hide").click(function(){

        $('#data').hide();
        $('#hide').hide();
        $('#show').show();

        return false;
    });

    $("#show").click(function(){

        $('#show').hide();
        $('#hide').show();
        $('#data').show();

        return false;
    });    

});

</script>

</html>
```

Comment: working fine for me - http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/2r6A5/1/

Comment: is there any error in your browser console

Comment: I just saw is you have wrap your code within html only. Isn't there head and body tag? Please ensure that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **HTML5 local storage** to achive the task as follows:

```
    <html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href='#' id='navigation'></a>
        <div id='data'><br>Data Here</div>
        <script>
            var navStatus = localStorage.getItem('navStatus');
            $(document).ready(function () {
                if (navStatus == undefined || navStatus == "") {
                    localStorage.setItem('navStatus', 'SHOW');
                    $('#navigation').text('HIDE');
                }
                else {
                    $('#navigation').text(navStatus);
                    if (navStatus == 'SHOW') {
                        $('#data').hide();
                    }
                }
                $("#navigation").click(function () {
                    if ($('#data').is(":visible")) {
                        navStatus = 'SHOW';
                    }
                    else {
                        navStatus = 'HIDE';
                    }
                    $(this).text(navStatus);
                    localStorage.setItem('navStatus', navStatus);
                    $('#data').toggle();
                    return false;
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Thanks this worked :)
I mainly program with PHP so I don't know too much about how jquery or html5 works

Comment: @Spudster please recheck my answer, There is a link text issue in previous code, which is solved

Comment: Did notice that the links where the other way around but I did fix that by just moving the links around ;)